# 2 Jquery ajax post requests. 2nd one gives error: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ipfs, js-ipfs

I have one `GET` request at first to retrieve a data structure. Then I perform some changes and perform a `PUT` request to send the data structure to the server and update the record. When I click the submit button on the on the first form it works as expected and when I submit the second one it executes as expected, but it logs 2 errors. Furthermore, when I make 2 edits successively it crashes the app and gives an `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error. The code related to the `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error is at the bottom.

[Image showing initial errors on update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6rsg.png)

[Range Error Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIe4d.png)

Here is my client side script:

```
<script>

const capitalize = ([first, ...rest]) => 
${first.toUpperCase()}${rest.join('')};
let patientDataRetrieved = false;
let _xhr,_xhr2 = null;

let patientID ;
let first_name;
let last_name;
let email;
let sex;
let date_of_birth;
let patient_phone;
let marital_status;
let emergency_contact1_rel ;
let emergency_contact1_phone;
let emergency_contact2_rel ;
let emergency_contact2_phone;
let spouse_phone;

$("body").on("contextmenu",function(e){
    return false;
});
$('body').bind('cut copy ', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});



document
    .getElementById("search")
    .addEventListener("submit",ev => {
        ev.preventDefault();
        patientID = ev.target.patientID.value;
        let uid = patientID;
        getPatientDetails()
        function getPatientDetails(){
            if(_xhr2!= null)
                _xhr2.abort();
            if(patientDataRetrieved===false){
                $(document).ready(()=>{
                    _xhr = $.ajax({
                        url: '/profile/'+uid,
                        type: 'GET',
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data){
                            //Instantiate Variables of User Data
                            let userdata = data;
                            console.log(userdata);
                            first_name = userdata.first_name;
                            last_name  = userdata.last_name;
                            sex = userdata.sex;
                            email = userdata.email;
                            let blood_type = userdata.blood_type;
                            date_of_birth = userdata.date_of_birth;
                            spouse_phone = userdata.spouse_phone;
                            patient_phone = userdata.patient_phone;
                            marital_status =userdata.marital_status;
                            spouse_phone = userdata.spouse_phone;
                            emergency_contact1_rel = userdata.emergency.contact1.relationship;
                            emergency_contact1_phone = userdata.emergency.contact1.phone;
                            emergency_contact2_rel = userdata.emergency.contact2.relationship;
                            emergency_contact2_phone = userdata.emergency.contact2.phone;

                            let chronic_illnesses = userdata.chronic_illnesses;
                            let past_surgeries = userdata.past_surgeries;
                            let allergies = userdata.allergies;
                            let long_term_medication = userdata.long_term_medication;

                            //Append User Data to respective td in table
                            $(".firstname").append(capitalize(first_name));
                            $(".lastname").append(capitalize(last_name));
                            $("#blood_type").val(blood_type);
                            $(".sex").append(capitalize(sex));
                            $(".date_of_birth").append(date_of_birth);
                            $(".patient_phone").append(patient_phone);
                            $(".marital_status").append(capitalize(marital_status));
                            $(".spouse_phone").append(spouse_phone);

                            $(".emergency_contact1_rel").append(capitalize(emergency_contact1_rel));
                            $(".emergency_contact1_rel").append(", Phone: "+emergency_contact1_phone);
                            $(".emergency_contact2_rel").append(capitalize(emergency_contact2_rel));
                            $(".emergency_contact2_rel").append(", Phone: "+emergency_contact2_phone);
                            $("#chronic_illnesses").val(chronic_illnesses);
                            $("#past_surgeries").val(past_surgeries);
                            $("#allergies").val(allergies);
                            $("#long_term_medication").val(long_term_medication);
                            document.getElementById("patientData").style.display ="block";
                            patientDataRetrieved = true;
                            return true;


                        }
                        , error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err){
                            alert('text status '+textStatus+', err 
'+err)
                        }

                    });

                });
            }
        }


    });

document.getElementById("editForm").addEventListener("submit", ev =>{
        ev.preventDefault();
    updatePatientInfo()
        function updatePatientInfo() {
        if(_xhr!=null){_xhr.abort()}
            let formData = {
                first_name: first_name,
                last_name: last_name,
                email: email,
                blood_type: $("#blood_type").val(),
                sex: sex,
                date_of_birth:date_of_birth,
                patient_phone:patient_phone,
                marital_status:marital_status,
                spouse_phone: spouse_phone,
                emergency_contact1_relationship:emergency_contact1_rel,
                emergency_contact1_phone:emergency_contact1_phone,
                emergency_contact2_relationship:emergency_contact2_rel,
                emergency_contact2_phone: emergency_contact2_phone,
                chronic_illnesses: $("#chronic_illnesses").val(),
                past_surgeries: $("#past_surgeries").val(),
                allergies: $("#allergies").val(),
                long_term_medication: $("#long_term_medication").val(),
                uid: patientID,
            };


            _xhr2 = $.ajax({
                url: "/edit_record_process",
                type: "PUT",
                data: formData,
                datatype:"text",
                encoded:true,
                cache: false,
                success:function(data){
                    if(data){
                        window.location.reload()
                    }
                },
                error: (err)=>{
                    alert(err);
                }
            });
        }
});
```

Here's the server side code:

```
app.get("/profile/:uid",   function (req, res){
//const current_user =
//const current_user =
const uid = req.params.uid;

db.ref("user_file_ref").on("value", snapshot=>{
    snapshot.forEach( dataSnapshot=>{
        if(uid === dataSnapshot.val().user_id){
            //line referenced in range error 
            getFileFromNet(dataSnapshot.val().ipfs_ref).then( result => 
  {
                const hash = JSON.parse(result);
                let decrypted_string = decrypt(hash);
                let return_data = JSON.parse(decrypted_string);
                 return res.send(return_data);
            }).catch((err) =>{
                return console.log(err);
            });
        }else{

        }
    })
})
return true;
});

app.put("/edit_record_process",  (req,res)=>{
let first_name = req.body.first_name;
let last_name= req.body.last_name;
let blood_type = req.body.blood_type ;
let sex = req.body.sex ;
let date_of_birth= req.body.date_of_birth ;
let email = req.body.email ;
let patient_phone= req.body.patient_phone ;
let userID = req.body.uid;
let marital_status= req.body.marital_status ;
let emergency= {
    contact1:
        {
            "relationship":req.body.emergency_contact1_relationship,
            "phone": req.body.emergency_contact1_phone
        },
    contact2:
        {
            "relationship":req.body.emergency_contact2_relationship,
            "phone": req.body.emergency_contact2_phone
        }
};
let chronic_illnesses = req.body.chronic_illnesses ;
let past_surgeries = req.body.past_surgeries ;
let allergies = req.body.allergies ;
let long_term_medication = req.body.long_term_medication ;
const userdata = {
    "first_name" : first_name,
    "last_name" : last_name,
    "sex": sex,
    "blood_type": blood_type,
    "date_of_birth":date_of_birth,
    "email":email,
    "patient_phone": patient_phone,
    "marital_status": marital_status,
    "emergency": emergency,
    "chronic_illnesses": chronic_illnesses,
    "past_surgeries":past_surgeries,
    "allergies": allergies,
    "long_term_medication": long_term_medication,
}
let userdata_string = JSON.stringify(userdata);
let encrypted_user_data = JSON.stringify(encrypt(userdata_string));
sendFileToNet(encrypted_user_data).then((ipfs_object)=>{
    let ipfs_path = ipfs_object.path;
    db.ref("user_file_ref").on("value", snapshot=>{
        snapshot.forEach(dataSnapshot => {
            if(userID === dataSnapshot.val().user_id){
                dataSnapshot.ref.update({ipfs_ref:ipfs_path}).then(()=> 
{
                    return res.sendStatus(201);
                }).catch((err)=>{
                    console.log(err)
                })

            }
        })
    })
});
});
```

IPFS API code:

```
const sendFileToNet = async (file_data) => {
const cid = function (data) {
    return client.add(data).then(cid =>{return cid;}).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)})
}
const real_cid = await cid(file_data);
return real_cid;
 }

const getFileFromNet = async (cid) =>{
const stream = client.cat(cid)
let data = ''
for await (const chunk of stream) {
    // chunks of data are returned as a Buffer, convert it back to a 
string
    data += chunk.toString()
}
return data;
 }
```

Comment: Looks like the error is on the server-side in server.js on line 138. So, that code would be needed to answer your question.

Comment: ```res.send(return_data);``` is what is referenced. Do you think the two responses and blocking each other?

Comment: Like I said, please provide the server code.

Comment: I added the server side code. the /profile responds to the first request and the /edit_user responds to the second one.

Comment: Which line is line 138?

Comment: The ```res.send(return_data);``` line in the /profile router

Comment: What are you using for `decrypt`?

Comment: I am using aes-256-ctr from the crypto module